# NextJS 13 App on AWS Amplify Shows Raw Page Data Instead of Rendered Page After Chrome Tab Wakeup

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, next.js13

I am developing a NextJS application that displays data loaded from an API using fetch, hosted on AWS Amplify. The application functions correctly under normal circumstances.

However, when I use Google Chrome and the application tab goes into inactive/sleep mode, upon returning to the tab, the page fails to render properly.
Instead of displaying the formatted page, it shows what appears to be raw page representation data.

[Screen of leagueofsmurfs.gg raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGDb9.png)

This issue occurs every time the tab is reactivated, but I have not tested it in other browsers. There are no error messages in the console when this happens.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Open [leagueofsmurfs.gg](https://www.leagueofsmurfs.gg/) in a Google Chrome.
2. Allow the tab to go inactive for a while.
3. Return to the tab the browser.
4. Observe that raw text data is displayed instead of the website.

Environment Details:

- NextJS Version: 13.4.1
- Google Chrome Version: 120.0.6099.225
- Operating System: Windows 11

I tried to check in logs, but there is nothing.
It is a simple application and it is not doing anything fancy.